# How to remove a string which contains a particular substring in java?

Tags: java, string

This is for processing a text file .

For example `loved` ,`loving`.. I want to remove all words which have sub string `lov`..

Comment: use `contains()` method

Answer (score 6):

You can check if a String contains a specific String by using [String#contains](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)) method.

```
if (word.contains("lov"))
{
   //remove
}
```

For more details on how contains works see 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: why people are downvoting here ? I understand that this doesn't explain it, but it answers the question, so rather than downvoting, why don't you comment

Comment: @JigarJoshi No Idea..

Comment: people shouldn't do that. +1 from me

Answer (score 3):

Try following code

```
String base = "loved";
String toRemove = "lov";
if (base.contains(toRemove)) {
    base=base.replaceAll(toRemove, "");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: working nice in my case.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex like this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "I loved locking lovers";
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\blov.*?\\b", ""));
}
```

o/p :

```
I  locking // 2 spaces between I and locking (leading and trailing)..
```

Comment: PS : pardon my vulgarity in `s`. :P